# How could I enable print statement in pytest looponfail mode?

Tags: python, pytest

I execute `py.test` like this : `py.test -s -f`, `-f` is `looponfail` mode and `-s` is `--capture=no` mode.

But `print()` statement is allowed only when the test is fail. If all tests succeeded, all `print()` in all codes doesn't work.

How could I enable `print()` statement even in `looponfail` mode?

- Python 3.4
- Py.test 2.7.2

Answer (score 0):

You should just update to newer `pytest`. Looks like this problem was fixed in `pytest=2.9.0`.